# How to match nested LaTeX macros with re in Python?

Tags: python, regex, python-re, curly-braces

I wanted to match LaTeX macros correctly even the nested ones. See the following:

```
s = r'''
firstline
\lr{secondline\rl{ right-to-left
        \lr{nested left-to-right} end RTL }
        other text
}
\rl{ last \lr{end line 
} end RTL }
'''
```

For instance, in the above, I want to match the `\lr` macro with its content. I have tried the following but none of them worked correctly:

```
re.findall(r'(?:\\lr\{.*\})', s, re.DOTALL)
['\\lr{secondline\\rl{ right-to-left\n        \\lr{nested left-to-right} end RTL }\n        other text\n}\n\\rl{ last \\lr{end line \n} end RTL }']
```

even non-greedy version did not work in this case:

```
re.findall(r'(?:\\lr\{.*?\})', s, re.DOTALL)
['\\lr{secondline\\rl{ right-to-left\n        \\lr{nested left-to-right}',
 '\\lr{end line \n}']
```

I need some regular expression to match it correctly, similar to nested parentheses, here I have nested curly brackets for LaTeX macros.

## edit:

I'd like to get the following matches:

```
['\\lr{secondline\\rl{ right-to-left\n        \\lr{nested left-to-right} end RTL }\n        other text\n}', 
'\\lr{nested left-to-right}',
'\\lr{end line \n}']
```

It would be perfect if I knew about the level of nesting, something like the below:

```
[('\\lr{secondline\\rl{ right-to-left\n        \\lr{nested left-to-right} end RTL }\n        other text\n}',1) 
('\\lr{nested left-to-right}',2)
('\\lr{end line \n}',1)]
```

Comment: If you can `pip install regex`, then you can use [this code](https://tio.run/##TY/BasMwDIbveor/ZntdC2W3wegL9FR2a1oYi5IYXDvIGmSkfvZszsaYbpI@fZLGTx1SfFoWfxuTKIR7nogyXiDGGOq8ZA0@MjVB5szvKbY1bSTMEN8PutW0Ddwp4TcqGDkrt6j12l/BAo4tTq9HlD826cAC5Ump0OoMb1lXRYXrJtD/wXoTjeKjWpynXS/pY7R7hy4JJvj488Cu87H1ymLFNN8y28z28Hy@zuWy2dztYe/cQ3HmEdld4JblCw).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks. This is great. How Could I get all nested `\lr`?

Comment: Please add the expected output to the question.

Comment: Please take a look at the new edition.

Comment: I doubt you can get nesting level with regex. So, all I can suggest is `[x.group() for x in regex.finditer(r'\\lr(\{(?:[^{}]++|(?1))*})', s, overlapped=True)]`, see [demo](https://tio.run/##TY5NSwQxDIbv/RXvra37AeJNWPYPeJK97ayw2MxMobYlzcrI2N8@2lHE3JI8efLmDxlTfFgW/5YTC5gGmpQqOIC11qr3XCT4SKoLPBd6TdG1tuMwg/0wyk7SLlAvCr/VwEhFyKHN234FKyg6PJ@eUP/YJCMxhCZRVa3OcC2yKhrcPkH9P2yZVGYfxeA87QdOt2ws@sSY4ONP/n3vo/NCbFh33y7Tzeb4eH6Z62Wz@TTHe2vvqtVblC3SO3G45kzucOIb2QvssnwB).

Comment: Great. Could you post your code as an answer to my question?

Comment: Isn't it possible to do this with re?

Comment: No, `re` can't do a lot of things.

Comment: Really appreciate your time to solve my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With PyPi regex module (after installing it with `pip install regex`) you can use

```py
import regex

s = r'''
firstline
\lr{secondline\rl{ right-to-left
        \lr{nested left-to-right} end RTL }
        other text
}
\rl{ last \lr{end line 
} end RTL }
'''

print( [x.group() for x in regex.finditer(r'\\lr(\{(?:[^{}]++|(?1))*})', s, overlapped=True)] )
# => ['\\lr{secondline\\rl{ right-to-left\n        \\lr{nested left-to-right} end RTL }\n        other text\n}', '\\lr{nested left-to-right}', '\\lr{end line \n}']
```

See the [Python demo](https://tio.run/##TY5NSwQxDIbv/RXvra37AeJNWPYPeJK97ayw2MxMobYlzcrI2N8@2lHE3JI8efLmDxlTfFgW/5YTC5gGmpQqOIC11qr3XCT4SKoLPBd6TdG1tuMwg/0wyk7SLlAvCr/VwEhFyKHN234FKyg6PJ@eUP/YJCMxhCZRVa3OcC2yKhrcPkH9P2yZVGYfxeA87QdOt2ws@sSY4ONP/n3vo/NCbFh33y7Tzeb4eH6Z62Wz@TTHe2vvqtVblC3SO3G45kzucOIb2QvssnwB) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2tbdEu/1).

Note also the `overlapped=True` option used with `regex.finditer` that allows matching nested occurrences.

*Details*:

- `\\lr` - `\lr` string
- `(\{(?:[^{}]++|(?1))*})` - Group 1 (defined to be referred to while recursing):

  - `\{` - a `{` char
  - `(?:[^{}]++|(?1))*` - zero or more repetitions of
  - `[^{}]++` - one or more chars other than `{` and `}` without the possibity to re-match the text again in case backtracking is triggered (i.e. it is matched possessively)
  - `|` - or
  - `(?1)` - Group 1 pattern recursed
  - `}` - a `}` char.